# How to specify device detection/initialisation order

Tags: pulseaudio

Lately, it has been taking more than one minute after session start for pulseaudio to list and activate my internal sound chip, which is annoying.

After inspecting the logs and the timestamps, it seems that pulseaudio actually gets delayed because of the initialisation of my USB webcam (presumably as a sound source).

I am not really bothered by the USB webcam taking time to fire up, but I would like it not to delay my default sink being available.

How can I tell pulseaudio to first get the internal sound chip's sink active, and only then try other devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Have a look at `/etc/pulse` for the configuration. The startup scripts are `default.pa` and `system.pa` (system mode). The module responsible for going through the ALSA sources is [module-udev-detect](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-udev-detect), however, there's no way to configure order, or to ignore a device.

So there's no easy way to do what you want.